# How to show phone keyboard while using a bluetooth keyboard device

Tags: windows-10-mobile, bluetooth, keyboard

I want to use a bluetooth keyboard device in my windows 10 mobile phone.

While doing so, I also want to use my phone's pop-up keyboard as well (which is, being able to use both phone's keyboard and bluetooth device).

Is there a way of doing that?